# Using a remote Powershell Session to change a service username/password

Tags: windows, powershell, invoke-command, remote-connection, win32serviceutil

I have a list of servers, and then another list of services on each of those servers. I am trying to remove it, change a few values in the .bat and then install the services again. Right now I have started a remote Powershell Session using

```
$PSsession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential
Enter-PSSession -Session $PSsession
```

I have been mainly using the `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {//somecodehere} -Session $PSsession` in order to run each of the commands that I have used so far. My initial approach was to use `sc.exe config $serviceName obj=$username password=$passwd`, but each time I make the change on the remote server, it tells me that there is a NativeCommandError and that there is a logon issue with the service.

Is there a way that I can use the credentials provided by the user in order to change the username/password of a service in a secure way? Or does anyone have any recommendations on a better approach I could research?

Comment: Sounds like you may be hitting the double hop issue. Since you’re using sc.exe anyways, can you use it remotely against the system instead of powershell remoting?

Comment: Use something like \\computername\c$   You need the dollar sign.  See : http://woshub.com/enable-remote-access-to-admin-shares-in-workgroup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my solution to my own problem was to create a script and copy it over to the server. Then it ran the `sc.exe` command inside of the machine itself. Since it is another machine, you can't send the credentials through as variables if they are a `SecureString`. So my solution is just to create those variables normally and then make sure to delete them afterwards.

If you are working with confidential data, don't forget that you usually need to overwrite the variable 3 times before deleting it.

Comment: Please mark as an answer.